# Network Video Buffering

Tags: network

We are facing some issue in our office internet. We are using Airtel 80mbps as an primary WAN link.

When we play Particular live video channel from device, say name as **A**, the video is buffering more when compared to other low speed service provider like BSNL.

With BSNL 4mbps internet connection same video channel and same device, the video is playing fine without buffering in same device.
If I check with a different device, say name **B**, video is streaming without buffering in both the network.

I need to find why the device A stream a lot in Airtel network and why its playing fine in BSNL network.
If I take the tracert of both internet service provider there is not drop in the connection, but the routing is traces is different area.

Can anyone help me to find the solution?

Comment: Welcome to Network Engineering!  Unfortunately, there's little you can do, other than to choose the provide with the best performance.  You can talk to Airtel to see what they  can do.  Since the problem lies in your provider networks, this question is, sadly, off-topic here.